# How to modify some arrays and not modifying others when we pass them in an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following C++ code. I am okay with modification on the content of array x[] as we pass it through the function modify but I don't want the content of the array z to be modified as we pass it. I am getting several errors in my attempt to do that. Could you help me please?
It seems I have errors with the initialization of the matrix m in the function also.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void modify(int y[], int f[], const int size)
{
    int m[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        m[i] = f[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        y[i] = 2 * y[i];
        m[i] = 2 * m[i];
        cout << "y[" << i << "]=" << y[i] << "\t"<<endl;
        cout << "m[" << i << "]=" << m[i] << "\t"<<endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main(){
    int x[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int z[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {   cout << "x[" << i << "]=" << x[i]<<"\t"<<endl;
        cout << "z[" << i << "]=" << z[i] << "\t"<<endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    modify(x,z,6);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "x[" << i << "]=" << x[i] << "\t" << endl;
        cout << "z[" << i << "]=" << z[i] << "\t" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int m[size]` is not standard c++. Some compilers support it as an extension, but it is not portable. `std::vector` is a portable alternative.

Comment: Why not use standard container classes (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::array`), then pass some by reference and others by value?

Comment: Ok thank you Francois and crashmstr. I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. This is the final code after the fix. I don't want to change on z but without using const.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void modify(int [], int [], int);

int main()
{

int x[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int z[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cout << "x[" << i << "]=" << x[i]<<"\t"<<endl;
    cout << "z[" << i << "]=" << z[i] << "\t"<<endl;
}
cout << endl;
modify(x,z,6);
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cout << "x[" << i << "]=" << x[i] << "\t" << endl;
    cout << "z[" << i << "]=" << z[i] << "\t" << endl;
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void modify(int y[], int f[], int size)   
{
vector<int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    m.push_back(f[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    y[i] = 2 * y[i];
    m[i] = 2 * m[i];
    cout << "y[" << i << "]=" << y[i] << "\t"<<endl;
    cout << "m[" << i << "]=" << m[i] << "\t"<<endl;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the parameter `f` of `modify` an array of `const int`. This way, no modifications can be made to the contents of `f`.

```
void modify(int y[], const int f[], const int size)
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++, you can use the `const` keyword to specify that something must not be changed.

The statement `void modify(int y[], const int f[], const int size)` indicates that `f` will not be changed by the function, therefore you may provide a `const` argument. Attempting to modify the object through `f` will produce a compilation error.

The statement `const int z[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};` indicates that `z` must not be changed. If you accidentally try to modify `z` or use it in a context where it may change, the compiler will produce a compilation error.